# PHP web application concurrency and load balancing

Tags: php, web-applications, concurrency, load-balancing

In PHP web applications concurrency and load balancing is done by the server or Application itself?

If we write application in pure PHP (not using a framework) it will handle the concurrency and load balancing ?

eg:-
          web site have 10 items to sell,
          But 1000 customers try to buy it in same time,
          what will happen

If we use a PHP framework(cakePHP, Codeignator) is it add additional code to our application ?

Other thing is we don't want to worry about the concurrency, do the error handling and the give rest to do the Server or We have to think about concurrency handling in our application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load balancing is usually handled by a server framework. PHP will not natively do any load-balancing for you. If your website cannot handle 1000 customers at the same time, your website will become unavailable.

Comment: If we use a PHP framework(cakePHP, Codeignator) is it add additional code to our application ?
Other thing is we don't want to worry about the concurrency, do the error handling and the give rest to do the Server or We have to think about concurrency handling in our application.

Comment: Provided you are going the "easy" route (think AWS load-balancer in front of separate instances of your site), no, you would not need to worry about concurrency. Every situation has an asterix, however, but in general, with server frameworks like those available at Amazon, you can have mirrored webservers connected to one database backend, and a load-balancer in front, so that you will have multiple web instances handling the workflow, and the load-balancer working out which customer to send to which machine.

Comment: thank you very much. Now i got a idea about it.

Answer (score 2):

No, PHP doesn't do any load balancing for you. Concurrency is a matter of intent here. There is no such thing as **handling concurrency for you**. It's a question of what do you want to happen when two concurrent requests come in. PHP is built on a per-request model. This means each individual request is handled by PHP in parallel. So PHP doesn't care that you have multiple concurrent requests coming in at the same time. They are treated separately.

Load balancing is normally handled by a separate load balancing software (like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) or [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)). Concurrency is normally handled by the external streams and servers that manage the various data you want controlled via specific requirements, like your database, a key/value store like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [reddis](http://redis.io/), or job managers/queues like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) or [zmq](http://www.zeromq.org/), or your mail server. These are all the things PHP communicates with on a regular basis and are usually responsible for the various tasks that involve your user's interaction with your web based application. PHP itself is just a very thin middleman that allows you to script and control how all of these interactions will work out.